# How can I compare 2 data in 1 table using where statement?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
$users = User::where('id', 'parent_id')->get();
```

The id and the parent_id are in the same table. I want to get all of the data from the users table where the id and parent_id are equal. How can I do that in Laravel?

Comment: `where('id', '=', 'parent_id')` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, pls provide enough information to answer the question. At least name the programming language

Comment: This question makes barely any sense... Please elaborate on your question...

Comment: in my users table i have a parent_id column because in my system you can register thru referal link. if you register using a referal link, the id of the referer will be saved to your parent_id column. what i want is to get all the users that doesnt have any referals.. i cant figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you want to know how to check if the user has no referrals. You can do it like this:

## Add referrer Relation in your user model.

```
public function referrer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

You can then query it like this:

```
User::doesntHave('referrer')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$users = User::whereColumn('id', 'parent_id')->get();
```

Comment: in my users table i have a parent_id column because in my system you can register thru referal link. if you register using a referal link, the id of the referer will be save to your parent_id column. what i want is to get all the users that doesnt have any referals.. i cant figure out how to do it